# Add liquidity by code is failing

Tags: solidity, gas, uniswap, liquidity-provider

I have the following code:

```
contract Test is ERC20, Ownable {

    address constant routerAddress = 0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E;

    constructor(uint initialSupply) ERC20("Test", "TST") public {
        _mint(address(this), initialSupply);
        
        // Do your burn here / renounce ownership
    }
    
    function addLiquidity(
        uint256 tokenAmount
    ) payable public {

        approve(routerAddress, tokenAmount);
        IUniswapV2Router02 pancakeRouter = IUniswapV2Router02(routerAddress);
        // add the liquidity
        pancakeRouter.addLiquidityETH{value: msg.value}(
            address(this),
            tokenAmount,
            0, // slippage is unavoidable
            0, // slippage is unavoidable
            owner(),
            block.timestamp + 360
        );
    }

}
```

When I press send in remix I get the following warning:

```
Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
Internal JSON-RPC error. { "code": -32000, "message": "execution reverted" }
```

This is the transaction: https://dashboard.tenderly.co/tx/bsc-testnet/0x721f65a7d90aa713b3a4af0ba66b59b85f96a74b3543184e015abb470e631065

and the contract address: 0x19Aa715521Cfd7B525e6a05c235e8E750ea4786c

[image]

Any clue of what's wrong here? Any way to set msg.value != 0?
I am having issues with any interaction with router v2 function, so I would appreciate any guide

Edit 1: this is happening also in mainnet

Answer (score 0):

You are using and address as a contract, but that address isn't a contract.

```
address constant routerAddress = 0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E;


IUniswapV2Router02 pancakeRouter = IUniswapV2Router02(routerAddress);
```

The `0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E` isn't a contract on bsc testnet.

That address exists is the pancake router on bsc so the error there is something else.

Comment: But it is in mainnet and it is failing there as well. Do you have any advice on how to fix it?

Comment: @DiegoGomez You haven't provided a transaction on mainnet so I can't comment on the error there.

Comment: this is the transaction in main net: https://dashboard.tenderly.co/tx/bsc/0x9ef98ba7e00e7e6e9eca42b32b8558292a9cb26ed6c421a62f0b6e8ad7c2bcab

Comment: @DiegoGomez For some reason [PancakeFactory](https://bscscan.com/address/0xca143ce32fe78f1f7019d7d551a6402fc5350c73) fails while trying to create the token pair. I see you have used 3M gas, did you try with more gas like 5M or 6M?